# Autolayout and proportional positioning

Tags: ios, autolayout

I suppose that my situation should be a common problem, but I'm really new to AutoLayout and to me it seems particularly complicated:

I want to make a layout to be suitable with 3.5 inches and 4 inches screens. 
This is the view for 4 inches displays:

[image]

And here is the view for a 3.5 inches display:

[image: 3.5 inches display]

What I need is essentially make the spaces between the segmented control and the yellow and blue view proportional to the screen size I suppose.

**My solution (that doesn't work):**

1)Adding constraints for top/bottom vertical spaces of the segment control using `less or equal to`.

2)Adding constraints to the other views to keep their positions (for example the blue view has a bottom spacing to the main view equal to zero, the yellow view has a fixed top spacing).

In my mind the constraints of point 1) just scale down when the main view scales... but it doesn't happen... and the segment view just move behind the other views maintaining the spacing defined as **max value** of the "Less then or equal to" definition.

How can I solve this common problem?

Have I to create spacer views for this situation? and in that case how you'd set up them?

Comment: This might help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521360/nsview-contraints-how-can-i-force-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-subview-to-stay-consta)

Comment: @iRaviiVooda thanks. At the moment it seems to be the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There is an pure autolayout solution:

1. Add vertical space constraint [yellowView]-(80@500)-[segmentView]
2. Add second vertical space constraint [segmentView]-(>=5)-[blueView]