# Xamarin forms how to retain spacing and other dimensions for controls, images and Icons across the screen?

Tags: xamarin, autolayout, xamarin.forms

do I need to have different images for different screen sizes for iOS for (4s 5s, and above)?
how can we set retain dimensions of images/Icons and controls across the screen sizes and resolutions in iOS (using Xamarin forms).
please refer this to understand problem 
[Autolayout and proportional positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192907/autolayout-and-proportional-positioning?rq=1)

but I need solution for xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using different solutions like:

Naming convention

```
iphone 4 = "image.png"
iphone 5,6 (or retina) = "image@2x.png"
iphone 6+ = "image@3x.png"
```

Getting the device width and height with the dependency service:

iOS

```
        public double Width
        {
            get
            {
                return UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
            }
        }

        public double Height
        {
            get
            {
                return UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
            }
        }
```

Android

```
  public double Width
    {
        get
        {
            var ctx = Forms.Context;
            var metrics = ctx.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
            return (ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels));
        }
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get
        {
            var ctx = Forms.Context;
            var metrics = ctx.Resources.DisplayMetrics;

            return (ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels));
        }
    }
```

And with that I can resize the images depending on the screen size, for example ScreenWidth/3.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS I use PaintCode. Then I have in Xamarin.Forms a view named: IconView and a custom renderer in iOS that draws the Icon (image) with PaintCode.

When Xamarin.Forms resizes the IconView, the custom renderer redraws. (You have to do the redraw on the OnPropertyChanged method:

```
// IconViewRenderer.cs
...
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == "Icon" || e.PropertyName == "X" || e.PropertyName == "Y" || e.PropertyName == "Width" || e.PropertyName == "Height")
            SetNeedsDisplay ();
    }

...
    public override void Draw (CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
    {
        base.Draw (rect);

        var iconView = (IconView)Element;
        switch (iconView.Icon) {
        case IconView.IconKind.SomeIcon:
            PaintCode.DrawSomeIcon (rect);
        case IconView.IconKind.SomeOtherIcon:
            PaintCode.DrawSomeOtherIcon (rect);
        ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, What exactly SetNeedsDisplay does? means how could it invoke Draw in custom Renderer?

Comment: It tells iOS that the view must be rerendered, which eventually leads to Draw being called.